# How can i learn mytime pre midnight or after midnight?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

i send any function a datetime  is_PM_AM("23:00.00")  if it is pm ,it must be return true or else? But how?
mytime ="23:30:00"

```
function(Datetime mytime) {
    if (Datetime.midnight < mytime) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: is this Javascript ? or C# ? or what ? I think you should start with Beginning C#.NET..

Comment: Code sample looks like Javascript. Don't knock him, help him rephrase the question.

Comment: Just look at his profile, he do not accept any answer, just make people do his maintenance work.. and you can see 4-5 questions about DateTime in .NET. -1

Answer (score 4):

```
public bool IsTimePM(DateTime mytime)
{
    return (mytime.Hour >= 12 && mytime.Hour < 24);
}
```

also see [wikipedia - 12-hour clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock)